# Access buttons from layout programmatically inflated within another layout

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

I am inflating a list of layouts `programmatically` from a xml into another layout.

The end result looks like the following image.
[image]

The number of **`checkboxes`** is different on each run, how can i get their state and also add listeners to the image button? Ideally i want only one listener that has an id of the selected layout.

This is the xml code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/chk_item_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox_chkitem"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView_chkitem"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageButton_chkitem"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/checkBox_chkitem"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton_chkitem"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/stat_notify_more" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

And this is how i inflate the layouts

```
        val checkitemlist = listOf<ChecklistItem>(ChecklistItem("Categoria", "conteudo"),
            ChecklistItem("Categoria", "conteudo"),
            ChecklistItem("Categoria", "conteudo"),
            ChecklistItem("Categoria", "conteudo"))
    for (item in checkitemlist) {
        val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)
        val layout = inflater.inflate(io.ubivis.ier.R.layout.checklistitem_layout, null, false) as ConstraintLayout
        layout.textView_chkitem.text = item.textSimple
        checklist_content_layout.addView(layout)
    }
```

Comment: Is there any problem with `findViewById`?

Comment: Do you really need to do this programatically? Looks like you could do this with a recyclerview + adapter.

Comment: https://www.androidhive.info/2016/01/android-working-with-recycler-view/

Comment: Thank you, I will take a look at the recyclerview, maybe that's what I nedd.

Answer (score 0):

replace your code

```
   for (item in checkitemlist) {
            checklist_content_layout.removeAllViews()
            val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)
            val layout = inflater.inflate(io.ubivis.ier.R.layout.checklistitem_layout, null, false) as ConstraintLayout
            layout.textView_chkitem.text = item.textSimple
            checklist_content_layout.addView(layout)
        }
```